# In android studio, the BasicSamples project complains that "This app won't run unless you update Google Play services."

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I have looked everywhere for answers, and I have narrowed it down to the following code:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:BaseGameUtils')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
}
```

It insists in the bottom corner of android studio that:

```
A newer version of com.google.android.gms:play-services than 5.0.77 is available: 5.2.08
```

Now I have tried the default version of '+' I have tried '5.0.89', '5.0.89+', '5.+', '5.0.+' and so on, but when I run the program, it insists that I need to update my google play services, however it is version 5.0.89 on the tablet I am debugging/running on (nexus 7).

I have google play services in my SDK manager, I have basically every SDK version and addon, I don't see any reason why it should not work. I have also followed the tutorial for the app I am working on (TypeANumber) in which case you have to make achievements and get unique identifiers for the google play achievements, everything is set up but it will not run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In Android SDK Manager check Extras->Google Repository (if not installed than you must install it)